# How to center this on screen

Tags: html, css, centering

So as a newbie web developer I am stuck on how to center all 3 images in the middle of the screen. I read up on it and came across `margin:auto;`. Tried it, didn't work.

This is the CSS:

```
<style>
.social
{
float:left;
margin:5px;
}
.main_block
{
    margin:auto, auto;
}
</style>
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="main_block">
<a href="#"><img class="social" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"> <a href="#"><img class="social" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="Facebook"></a> <a href="#"><img class="social" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Google +"></a> </a>
</div>
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: There's a bunch of this style of question on this site.  Doing a quick search would help you out.  But, I will tell you this - the problem is with your `float: left` in your `.social`.  Also, you have a typo - .main_block should be `margin: auto auto;` - no comma, as you have entered.

Comment: Flexboxes fix this problem, but as we mostly still need to take heed for Internet Explorer (where it doesn't work), It's mostly common to do it with a small jQuery edit on `$(document).ready()` (or `load()`) to give the div the correct vertically centered alignment. It's mostly `height` subtracted from the `window.height` divided by two. But as I don't know the rest of your content it's hard to say the outcome.

Comment: @cale_b, I have tried it, No avail. I've also tried just margin: auto; doesn't work either. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "the problem is with your float: left".

Comment: `float:left` by definition causes all elements with that style to appear stacked up on the left side of the screen.  Remove `float: left` and see what happens.  And, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956577/centering-a-navigation-bar/21956640#21956640 - additionally, if you want something centered, you need to use `text-align: center` on the *containing* element, otherwise how does it know to center?

Comment: ... remove `float` and try `text-align` for horizontal centering. for screen center, search for `display:flex` or `table`, or even the oldish way to center via `position:absolute;` ... lots of answer here for a redundant question

Comment: @GCyrillus, I have tried text-align instead of float. The images appear beneath each other (which I don't want) and are to the left of the screen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E6M2z/2/ oldish way + `white-space:nowrap`

Comment: Okay, I give up, It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/H2yvS/1/)

You need to display the images as block and then apply margin auto

Also your HTML is not correct:

```
<div class="main_block">
    <div class="ib">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="social" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" /> 
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <img class="social" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/50/50/" alt="Facebook" />
            </a>
        <a href="#">
            <img class="social" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="Google +" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.social
{
    float: left;
}

.ib {
    display: inline-block;
}

.main_block {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Noo, I need the images side by side not beneath one another.

Comment: Yes! Finally! Thank you soo much! No other solutions worked expect for this one. I've been searching for a solution for about 2 hours now and have like 50 tabs open! Marked as accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you wanted them to stack over each other, or just to center them.

---

**Stack them over each other**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6M2z/1/)

To stack them over each other, you want to have `position:absolute;` in the `.social` tag, that way they won't try to avoid each other. The problem is, `margin:auto;` won't work then. The only solution I've found to fix this to to set the `left:` and `right:` positions to `1%;`.

---

**Just center them**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6M2z/)

This one is to just center them. You would just want to use `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;`. With this, you don't need to use `position:absolute;`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set a width on the main-block class and remove the comma.

Your style should look something like this:

```
.main_block
{
    width: 40em;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```